# Как сократить строки кода в замене hex значений

Tags: c#, wpf, инспекция-кода, hex

У меня есть код:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Test.bin";
        var path2 = @"C:\Test2.bin";
        var path3 = @"C:\Test3.bin";

        try
        {
            ReplaceData(path, 416, BitConverter.GetBytes(1.5F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path, 443, BitConverter.GetBytes(2.6F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path, 447, BitConverter.GetBytes(1.3F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path, 474, BitConverter.GetBytes(1.45F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));

            ReplaceData(path2, 512, BitConverter.GetBytes(2.5F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path2, 525, BitConverter.GetBytes(3.1F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path2, 555, BitConverter.GetBytes(5.3F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path2, 600, BitConverter.GetBytes(1.75F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));

            ReplaceData(path3, 315, BitConverter.GetBytes(1.2F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path3, 400, BitConverter.GetBytes(2.66F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path3, 450, BitConverter.GetBytes(3.3F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
            ReplaceData(path3, 468, BitConverter.GetBytes(2.75F * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void ReplaceData(string filename, int position, byte[] data)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream.Position = position;
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
```

Код получается слишком громоздкий и некрасивый, как мне произвести замену байтов в нескольких местах сократив код до минимума? (файлов для замены будет много)

Comment: Вам не нравится лишь только, что код слишком длинный? Вы не думали, что хардкодить (да по одному байту) в программе данные - дурной тон? Вы пачтите какой-то бинарь, но что вам мешает написать процедуру чтения патча из файла настроек? Или, раз у вас wpf, выкинуть диалог выбора файла пачта, потом чтение его, разбор и применение пачта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, добавить к вашему методу ReplaceData ещё один:

```
private static void ReplaceData(string path, int[] positions, float[] data){
    for(int i=0; i<positions.Lenght; i++){
        ReplaceData(path, positions[i], BitConverter.GetBytes(data[i] * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100));
    }
}
```

Либо, подправить текущий:

```
private static void ReplaceData(string path, int[] positions, float[] data){
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)) {
        for(int i=0; i<positions.Lenght; i++){
            var tmpData = BitConverter.GetBytes(data[i] * (float)NumericNorecoil1.Value / 100);
            stream.Position = positions[i];
            stream.Write(tmpData, 0, tmpData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

соответственно, код немного сократится:

```
ReplaceData(path,
            new int[]  { 416,  443,  447,  474   },
            new float[]{ 1.5f, 2.6f, 1.3f, 1.45f });
ReplaceData(path2,
            new int[]  { 512,  525,  555,  600   },
            new float[]{ 2.5f, 3.1f, 5.3f, 1.75f });
ReplaceData(path3,
            new int[]  { 315,  400,   450,  468   },
            new float[]{ 1.2f, 2.66f, 3.3f, 2.75f });
```

Answer (score 1):

Если цель уменьшить число строк кода, можно попробовать так:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReplaceData(@"C:\Test.bin", 416, Tb1);
        ReplaceData(@"C:\Test.bin", 443, Tb2);
        ReplaceData(@"C:\Test.bin", 447, Tb3);
        ReplaceData(@"C:\Test.bin", 474, Tb4);
    }

    public static void ReplaceData(string filename, int position, TextBox tb)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(float.Parse(tb.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream.Position = position;
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, однако иногда надо будет менять в 100+ местах

Comment: Вообще, если замен много, то можно иметь список позиций и значений под замену и проходиться в цикле. Ну и файл открывать один раз, а не на каждый вызов

Comment: прошу прощения, я не тот код залил